# excess "" in Qt CSV file creation

Tags: qt, csv

i'm coding in qt. i'm using this to create a csv file.

```
   QtCSV::StringData strData;
   QStringList strList0;
   int a=10; int b=20;
   QStringList strList;
   strList << QString::number(a) << QString::number(b);
   strData.addRow(strList);
   QFile my_file(fileName);
   if(my_file.open(QFile::WriteOnly ))
     QtCSV::Writer::write(my_file, strData);
```

the file created and data is writed. the problem is this method of writing  create this line of data:

```
""10","20""
```

the inner "" is excess. how can i write so that it remove? the other standard csv file does not have this and my file cannot open in some programs.

Comment: Try `QtCSV::Writer::write(my_file, strData, ",", "");`

Comment: thanks, it works good.